# How to fix Android 4.0.1 compiler classpath

Tags: android-studio, configuration, flutter-dependencies

when I start Android Studio 4.0.1 I get the following messages in the console:

Can you tell me, where and how to fix that, especially the error?

```
[   2804]   WARN - com.intellij.ide.ui.LafManager - List.rowHeight = 0 in IntelliJ; it may lead to performance degradation 

[   2804]   WARN - com.intellij.ide.ui.LafManager - Table.rowHeight = 0 in IntelliJ; it may lead to performance degradation 

[   2805]   WARN - com.intellij.ide.ui.LafManager - Tree.rowHeight = 0 in IntelliJ; it may lead to performance degradation 

[   3319]   WARN - nSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl - keymap "ReSharper" not found [Plugin: com.android.tools.ndk] 

[  11098]  ERROR - l.BuildProcessClasspathManager - Cannot add 'layoutlib-api.jar' from 'Android Support 10.4.0.1' to compiler classpath 
java.lang.Throwable: Cannot add 'layoutlib-api.jar' from 'Android Support 10.4.0.1' to compiler classpath
        at com.intellij.openapi.diagnostic.Logger.error(Logger.java:145)
        at com.intellij.compiler.server.impl.BuildProcessClasspathManager.computeCompileServerPluginsClasspath(BuildProcessClasspathManager.java:120)
        at com.intellij.compiler.server.impl.BuildProcessClasspathManager.getStaticClasspath(BuildProcessClasspathManager.java:48)
        at com.intellij.compiler.server.impl.BuildProcessClasspathManager.getBuildProcessPluginsClasspath(BuildProcessClasspathManager.java:34)
        at com.intellij.compiler.server.BuildManager.launchBuildProcess(BuildManager.java:1238)
        at com.intellij.compiler.server.BuildManager.lambda$null$10(BuildManager.java:799)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor.doRun(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:222)
        at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor.access$200(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:30)
        at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor$1.execute(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:201)
        at com.intellij.util.ConcurrencyUtil.runUnderThreadName(ConcurrencyUtil.java:221)
        at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor$1.run(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:190)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

[  11114]  ERROR - l.BuildProcessClasspathManager - Android Studio 4.0.1  Build #AI-193.6911.18.40.6626763 

[  11114]  ERROR - l.BuildProcessClasspathManager - JDK: 1.8.0_242-release; VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM; Vendor: JetBrains s.r.o 

[  11114]  ERROR - l.BuildProcessClasspathManager - OS: Linux 

[  11121]  ERROR - l.BuildProcessClasspathManager - Last Action:  

[  14281]   WARN - com.intellij.util.xmlb.Binding - no accessors for class org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.highlighter.KotlinDefaultHighlightingSettingsProvider 

[ 304893]   WARN - dea.sdk.SystemInfoStatsMonitor - CpuInfoFlags.fromExitCode(): unknown flag values '0x80'
```

Android Studio 4.0.1 is used for Flutter development.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the error has gone with Android Studio 4.1.
So this thread can be closed.